# TableLayoutPanel stops to visualize columns

Tags: c#, .net, tablelayoutpanel

In my Windows form I created a tableLayoutPanel with more than 1000 columns, I filled it with labels in each position of the table.
During the debugging operation I saw that the panel contains all the data that I wanted to have, but the form is not able to visualize them.[image][image]
Executing the application with less columns I don't have the problem of visualization.
Does anyone know the reason?

Edit: I prefered to use the tableayoutPanel to avoid the error "Sum of the columns' FillWeight values cannot exceed 65535" in case of datagridreview.

Edit 2: if I stay in the position where I stop seeing the values (in the second image for example) in the panel and execute again, I'm able to visualize the other part of my data.

Comment: why your using the tablelayout....better go with datagrid

Comment: I tried with datagrid but it gives me a problem in the total dimension of the columns as reported in my edited question